# How to create a background notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to implement a Service which permit to show a notification (daily, or after XX minutes) even if I close the application. (Actually, when I press back button, I finish the MainActivity...)

I need a runnable notification even if I didn't start the application (after rebooting the device for example, of course when the trigger is declanched)...

I tried some clear examples and tutorials but I doesn't find what I need.

Please HELP!

Thanks in advance,
Mohamed

Comment: my solution works or not?

Comment: No... Not exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with alarm manger:

```
public class AlarmHelper {

private Context context;
private AlarmManager alarmManager;
private static final String TAG = "AlarmHelper";
public final static String ALARM_ALERT_ACTION = "com.android.alarmclock.ALARM_ALERT";

public AlarmHelper(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
}

public void setNotifyAlarm(Long milliSecond) {

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = getNotifyPendingIntent();
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, milliSecond, pendingIntent);
    // alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, milliSecond, sender);
}

public void cancelNotifyAlarm() {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = getNotifyPendingIntent();
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}

private PendingIntent getNotifyPendingIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmExpireService.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
}

public void setExpireAlarm(int minute) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minute - 1);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = getExpirePendingIntent();
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
}

public void cancelExpireAlarm() {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = getExpirePendingIntent();
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}

private PendingIntent getExpirePendingIntent() {
    return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context,
            AlarmExpireService.class), 0);
}
```

}

Now in the AlarmExpireService.java:

```
public class AlarmExpireService extends Service {

// private static final String TAG = "AlarmExpireService";
private static final String TAG = "AlarmExpireService";


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //your logic for start activity or generate notification.
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    AppLog.Log(TAG, "On start command");
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

}

Now Register service in the manifest file:

```
 <service android:name="your_package.AlarmExpireService" />
```

For just call a method from AlarmHelper's setNotifyAlarm method and your work is done pass the time in millisecond (it will start after that time and notification will be pop up).

For more information take a reference of this links:
1. [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)
2. [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)
3.[Pending Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)